# Integral equation for novice.

Tags: integration

$$ \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} ny(y-\theta)^{n-1}dy = \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n(y-\theta)^n d(y-\theta) + \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n\theta(y-\theta)^{n-1}d(y-\theta)$$

Please explain this equation easily(no skipping steps.) as possible as you can.
Someone just explain to me with "It's just algebra." I know this is algebra. What i don't know is how this algebra make right side from left side.

Comment: If you're not able to understand simple algebraic operations, as stated in your previous post, you shouldn't even bother try to understand what an integral is.

Comment: I see that this is almost similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959087/order-statistic-integral. If this is the same as the earlier one, then please delete this question and edit the earlier one.

Comment: Is this website for the man who understand every simple algebraic operation? Someone who don't know about the simple algebraic operation can't ask twice for more explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum number of steps have been provided for your perusal:
$$\begin{align} & \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} ny(y-\theta)^{n-1}dy \\ =&  \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n(y-\theta+\theta)(y-\theta)^{n-1}dy \\  =&\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n\{(y-\theta)(y-\theta)^{n-1}+\theta(y-\theta)^{n-1}\}dy \\  =& \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n\{(y-\theta)(y-\theta)^{n-1}+\theta(y-\theta)^{n-1}\}d(y-\theta) \\  =& \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n(y-\theta)^n d(y-\theta) + \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} n\theta(y-\theta)^{n-1}d(y-\theta) \end{align}$$

See if this helps.

Comment: Perhaps the substitution $y \rightarrow z=y-\theta \implies \frac{dz}{dy}=1$ could also be a step.

Comment: Thanks. I want to practice this part with exercise, What is the name of chapter for this part?

Comment: @joseya7 No such name... You're welcome.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat  Can you explain how to go from line 3 to line 4? Because in line 3 we have $dy$ and in line 4 we have $d(y-\theta)$. Thanks.

Comment: @cgiovanardi Observe the first line of Piquito's Post and note that $\theta$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It have been simply used the fact that $$d(y-\theta)=dy$$ because $\theta$ is constant and the equality $$\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bg(x)dx=\int_a^b(f(x)+g(x))dx$$ Because of $$n(y-\theta)^n+n\theta(y-\theta)^{n-1}=n(y-\theta)^{n-1}(y-\theta+\theta)=ny(y-\theta)^{n-1}$$ equality proposed is valid.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. I want to practice this process with various exercise. Is there specific name of chapter for this integral?